# Lifecycle Manager Jobs Permission denied

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

while  Importing an unmanaged cluster the job error

Permission denied ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd2Tw.png)

Answer (score 2):

OpsCenter developer here. It's hard to give a meaningful answer with so little information.

- If you click through on the error, you'll get a more in-depth description.
- If you look at the opscenterd.log file, you'll find additional context. You can log the LCM job-events to that file by setting the 'lcm' logger to debug in opscenterd's logback.xml.

But if I'm guessing, you don't have filesystem permissions to write in the home directory of the user you're logging in as. Log in as the user you specified in your LCM ssh-credentials and try to touch ./test-file and see if you get a permissions error. If you do, you'll need to resolve that outside of LCM before you can proceed. LCM needs to write a temporary file to your home-directory.